# Measurability of the right-hand side of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measurable-functions

I am researching the existence and uniqueness of the global solution of the original differential equation (ODE) of the form:
$$\dot{x}(t) = f(t,x), \ \ t \geq 0 ; \ \ x(0) = x_0. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

There are many results that have been given, for example:

$\bullet$ In Khalil's book [1, Theorem 3.2], the assumptions made are $f(\cdot,x)$ is a piecewise continuous function for any given x and $f(t,\cdot)$ is a Lipschitz continuous function for all t then (1) has a global absolutely continuous (AC) solution on $[0, +\infty)$.

$\bullet$ In Sontag's book [2, Theorem 54, Proposition C.3.8], it says that if $f(\cdot,x)$ is a measurable function for any given x, and $\|f(t,x_0)\|$ is bounded for all t, and $f(t,\cdot)$ is a Lipschitz continuous function for all t then (1) has a global AC solution on $[0, +\infty)$.

$\bullet$ However, in Vidyasagar's book [3, Theorem (25), p.38], it is only assumed that $\|f(t,x_0)\|$ is bounded for all t and $f(t,\cdot)$ is a Lipschitz continuous function for all t then (1) has a global continuous and everywhere differentiable solution on $[0, +\infty)$.

The main issue is whether we need the measureability of $f(\cdot,x)$ for a given x or not? It is clear that in Khalil's book (piecewise continuous infers measureability and boundedness) and Sontag's need for the measureability of $f(\cdot,x)$, however in Vidyasagar's book this is not needed.

Is this an omission on the author's part? Because the proof of this result involves Picard's iterations where it is written $\int_{0}^{t} f(\tau, x_0)d\tau$. I think at least for this integral to exist then $f(\cdot, x_0)$ must be measurable. What do you think?

Also note that: The solutions in Vidyasagar's book are not AC (because a function that is continuous and differentiable everywhere is not necessarily AC). This is a solution with weaker properties than AC. What explanation could this possibly have for not mentioning the measure of $f(\cdot, x)$?

[1]https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Muhammad_Ahsan23/post/What_is_the_general_principle_of_designing_the_switching_control_in_sliding_mode_control/attachment/59d62f0dc49f478072e9f5e3/AS%3A272534484783104%401441988692243/download/H-K-Khalil-Nonlinear-Systems-3rd-Edition-2002.pdf

[2] http://www.sontaglab.org/FTPDIR/sontag_mathematical_control_theory_springer98.pdf

[3] https://wp.kntu.ac.ir/nobari/Nonlinear/VIDIASAGAR.pdf

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.